# send Email with new record from Database query

Tags: oracle, talend

i have query which give me information of ETL Error like this:

[image]

i create a Job: tOracleinput --->tsendMail which sends this Error logs to my Email.

What i want now is that: when i execute the Job again and again, it sends me only new Error logs. The Error logs which has been sent, will be not send again.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Read about `tOracleCDC` - https://help.talend.com/reader/NNO~fmVQU4rlkF9Depfdxw/JXvgNTorRK1zf3XyoitGag. Note - this is only available to the subscribed version.
One more option would be to change your Oracle source query to fetch only the newly `inserted` records from the table and let `Talend` do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

This is one. Pls treat this answer as an algo.

- Create a variable, called `ID_error_log = 1` in some properties file.
- Read this ID from properties file at the start of ETL job.
- In your ETL, when you're trying to fetch errorData, use this ID in query to fetch data like
  `select * from bla_bla_bla where id > context.ID`
- Send emails for these errors.
- At the end of the job, update the `ID_error_log` in properties file to the latest ID for which you sent an email.

So next time, as the ID is updated - records will not be duplicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you are trying to persist the data that you what to send through mail.
One possible solution is to write the error logs into a file/database, and then read all of the data from this file/database, and send it into tSendMail.